# php is it possible to post redirect get with form action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, post-redirect-get

I'm using this code in my form

```
form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"
```

Is there anyway I can POST-Redirect-GET when the form data is submitted by user? I'm trying to avoid duplicate form submissions from user hitting refresh.

like in this [example](https://wordsideasandthings.blogspot.com/2013/04/post-redirect-get-pattern-in-php.html)
.

I don't see how this could work if I'm using PHP_SELF in the form action. Any ideas?

Comment: _“I don't see how this could work if I'm using PHP_SELF in the form action.”_ - and I don’t see what makes you think these two things were even remotely connected …? What is the problem, knowing which URL to redirect back to? Well ask the right question then - https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20get%20current%20url

Comment: the problem is that I have other functions depending on the use of PHP_SELF, I want to PRG without having to go to another page. I want to set it up all in one page like in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using `PHP_SELF` like that is exploitable, [it allows for XSS](https://sarathlal.com/understand-avoid-php_self-exploits/). Just leave action blank like `action=""` and the form will submit to the page it's currently on.
2. If you want to prevent repeat submissions via refresh then issue a 302 redirect after receiving the form submission.

   ```
   header("Location: /somewhere_else.php", true, 302);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I actually have a sanitize function in my code, but didn't put it in this example because I thought it might confuse the issue.